# Javascript - Throw different error from inner function and general in the outer

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have the following code for my top/outer method "f":

```
async function f() {
   await g().catch(err => {...});
   ...
}
```

And this one for the method which is executed inside f():

```
async function g() {
   await something(); // Can fail because of server problems...

   if (true) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("cancelled", "Some custom message");
   }
}
```

Now, if in f, I want to throw the errors as instances of functions.https.HttpsError, I have thought to do:

```
async function f() {
   await g().catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unavailable", "Server error") // Unexpected errors... Will be good for errors coming from calling something() in g()

       /* Note: HttpsError -> constructor(type, message) */
    });

   ...
}
```

As you can see, I am handling the general errors, with the type "unavailable" and a general message "Server error".

But... what happens with the error coming from the conditional? How can I catch it in f(), and throw it? Its type is "cancelled" and the message is "Some custom message", but this way I am handling errors will result in a problem, as the "custom" error is an instance of the same class of error I am throwing in the outer function when catching errors from the inner.

I have thought to throw an object

```
async function g() {
     ...

     if (true) {
         const error = {
            type: "cancelled",
            message: "custom error",
         } 

         throw error;
     }
}
```

And then, in f() do:

```
     await g().catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.type || "unavailable", err.message || "Server error") // Unexpected errors... Will be good for errors coming from calling something() in g()

       /* Note: HttpsError -> constructor(type, message) */
    });
```

But the code doesn't look clean. Is this the common way to handle these situations? Any other better

Thank you. way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the error you get from `g()` to something else, the idiomatic way to do that is with a `catch` block:

```
async function f() {
    try {
        await g();
        // ...perhaps other things here as well...
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unavailable", "Server error");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Remember that in an `async` function, `await promise` will raise an error if the promise is rejected. You catch that error using `catch`, just like a synchronous error.

Comment: But, if g() is throwing an error which type and message are different from what I throw in f(), then is correct to throw an object { type: "x", message: "x" } and catch it like I described in the question?

Comment: @Raul - I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking there. Are you asking about the mechanics of exceptions in `async` functions? Or the contents of what you're throwing? Or...?